# Formatting Page Header in Excel Using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

The existing formatting of the center page header in each worksheet is not uniform and I would like it all to be Arial, font size 10, and bolded. Does anyone know how to extract only the text from the existing header or to remove the current formatting so that I can apply my new uniform formatting using VBA?

So far I have the following code:

```
Sub HeaderFinal()

    Dim HCntr as String
    HCntr = ActiveSheet.PageSetup.CenterHeader

    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .CenterHeader = "&""Arial,bold""&10" & HCntr
        .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
        .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
        .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(1.25)
        .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(1)
        .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
        .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
        .ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = False
        .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = True
        .CenterHorizontally = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: What isn't working?

Comment: I don't think there's any easy way to extract only the displayed text from the header: it's often mixed in with formatting codes.

Comment: The Center header formatting is not changing when I run this code.

Comment: But if you change the header manually, won't it change for all sheets? Isn't that kind of the point?

Comment: If you `Debug.Print HCntr` what do you see?

Answer (score 0):

`HCntr` includes the formatting info you want to change, it needs to be removed before you can add your own

Try the following:

```
Sub HeaderFinal()

Dim HCntr as String
HCntr = ActiveSheet.PageSetup.CenterHeader

HCntr = Right(HCntr , Len(HCntr ) - InStr(2, HCntr , "&"))

Do Until Not IsNumeric(Left(HCntr, 1))
    HCntr = Right(HCntr, Len(HCntr) - 1)
Loop

If Left(HCntr, 1) = " " Then HCntr = Right(HCntr, Len(HCntr) - 1)

With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .CenterHeader = "&""Arial,bold""&10" & HCntr
    .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
    .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
    .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(1.25)
    .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(1)
    .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
    .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
    .ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = False
    .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = True
    .CenterHorizontally = True
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: `If Left(HCntr, 1) Then` If it's what? That seems to be missing something? You mean `If Left(HCntr, 1) = "&" Then` ?

Comment: @Christofer Weber - Problem fixed, thanks for spotting that

Comment: Not sure, but maybe you need a `If Left(HCntr, 1) = """" Then HCntr = Right(HCntr, Len(HCntr) - InStr(2, HCntr, """"))` in there too, to catch the weird edge case of having changed the font, but the size being the original *11* Or not, that doesn't work with the space, but it did with "&"... this formatting is weird.

Comment: @Christofer Weber - You may be right about the edge case. And are completely correct about the weirdness of the header formats

Comment: As OP mentioned "in each worksheet ", suggest to do a `For each Wsh in ThisWorkbook.Sheets`